# Python: regex matching the opposite of what's desired

Tags: python, regex

I want my regex to find an url to be able to turn it into a html link.The regex will be used on links that look like the following: www.site.extension and https://site.extension. The regex is \S*.?w{3}.\S+.\S+ and it does give the desired result when using https://regexr.com/. When using my python script however, I get the opposite result of what's desired, so everything that isn't a link is seens as if it were, but the links aren't found.

The python code is:

```
testbestand = """TESTBESTAND

Div1 kjaskdjfiudhgjnkcvdnbk djskj ij g ijg jkdfnbdiiji jj iikdafnbn ojedfkj giqw34
Akdjfkjasdf

Div2 aksjdfkj sadfkjg sdkjiew kvckjeri cdkj sdkeridk erkire

Div3 kajkdjfkjakdjgsdghijskdg

Div 4 www.link.com

Div5
Table Left  Table Right
Table Left 2    Table Right 2
Table Left 3    Table Right 3
"""

fileContent = testbestand
toAddToFile = ""

#find links
pattern = re.compile(r'\S*\.?w{3}\.\S+\.\S+')
matches = re.split(pattern, fileContent)\

for match in matches:
    match = match.strip()

    if len(match) > 0:
        #TODO change to 'edit' file, instead of adding to it
        test = """<a href=" """ + match + """>" """ + match + "</a>"
        print(test)

        toAddToFile += """<a href=" """ + match + """>" """ + match + "</a>"
```

Thanks in advance for any help! If more info or code is needed, I'll provide it straight away.

Comment: If you want to match why do you split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you use `re.split`, which is designed to split the text *at* the patterns. Instead, use `re.findall:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\S*\.?w{3}\.\S+\.\S+')
matches = pattern.findall(fileContent)
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks! I'll mark it as the correct answer when the timer is done. It seems like it understood re.split wrong.

Comment: `re.findall` won't help preserve what aren't matched.

Comment: That's good for now, altough I might change the behavior of the code in the future, so I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `re.sub` instead of `re.split`:

```
toAddToFile = re.sub(r'(\S*\.?w{3}\.\S+\.\S+)', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', fileContent)
```